# How to export a variable in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to export **sentiment.pos** value to use in another file?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkNLv.png

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

const url = "mongodb+srv://<...>/data?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const databaseName = 'data'

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (error, client) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('Unable to connect database!')
    }
    const db = client.db(databaseName)

    db.collection('sentiment').findOne({ _id: new 
ObjectId('5fcb7c94945dfa94387a6c19') }, (error, sentiment) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log('Unable to fetch')
        }
        console.log(sentiment.pos)
        return sentiment.pos
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const {
    MongoClient,
    ObjectId
} = require('mongodb');

const url = "mongodb+srv://<...>/data?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const databaseName = 'data';

getSentimentPos = () => {
    let sentimentPos = null;

    MongoClient.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }, (error, client) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log('Unable to connect database!')
        }
        const db = client.db(databaseName)

        db.collection('sentiment').findOne({
            _id: new
            ObjectId('5fcb7c94945dfa94387a6c19')
        }, (error, sentiment) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log('Unable to fetch')
            }
            console.log(sentiment.pos)
            sentimentPos = sentiment.pos;
        })
    });
    return sentimentPos;
}
```